# Apache Flink + StateFul functions + Sprint boot -ProgramInvocationException:

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-flink, flink-stateful-functions, apache-stateful-functions

I'm pretty new to Apache flink and stateful functions just trying some code.

I created a simple stateful greeting application using spring boot and included all necessary dependencies, created a fat jar.

I'm trying to run this jar on flink standalone cluster using the below command

```
./flink run -c org.apache.flink.statefun.flink.core.StatefulFunctionsJob ./statefun-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I'm getting below exceptions
[image]

Can anyone let me know what is this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, it looks like you've got a value in the StateFun configuration that's an array instead of a string. If you have a configuration that's multi-valued, sometimes it just needs to be a comma-separated string, not an array.